# Is the series $ L = \sum_{i=2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n \log(n)} $ convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does $ L = \sum_{i=2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n \log(n)} $ converge or diverge?

I established that: 
$$
L \le I
  = \int^{\infty}_{2} \frac{1}{n \log(n)}
  = \lim_{n \to \infty} [ \ln(\log(n)) - \ln(\log(2)) ],
$$
and as $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \log(x) = \infty $, then $ L $ **diverges.**

But I'm not sure:

1. of the sense of the inequality,
2. about the conclusion.

Comment: Note that you proved that $I=\infty$, and if you start from $L \leq I$, you cannot say anything (because nothing is greater than $\infty$). However, the standard way of proof shows that actually $L \geq I$. Since $I=\infty$, then $L=\infty$.

Comment: You want to show that $L$ is *greater* than or equal to some integral that you can show is $+\infty$. Since $\frac{1}{x\log(x)}$ it is a decreasing function (on $(1,\infty)$ at least), it suffices to choose $L$ to be the left hand rectangle rule for a suitable integral. In fact it is the left hand rectangle rule for $I$, so in fact $L \geq I$ and $I=+\infty$ so $L=+\infty$.

Comment: @Ian thank you! it helped me to figure out the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is the *integral test*: the series (with positive terms) $\;\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\log n}$ converges (resp. diverges) if and only if the improper integral $\;\int_2^\infty\frac 1{x\log x}\,\mathrm dx$ converges (resp. diverges).

Now this integral is easy to calculate by substitution: setting $u=\log t$, we obtain
$$\int_2^A \frac 1{x\log x}\,\mathrm dx=\int_{\log 2}^{\log A} \frac{\mathrm d u}u=
\log\, \biggl|_{\log 2}^{\log A}=\log(\log A)-\log(\log 2)\xrightarrow[A\to\mkern1mu+\infty]{}+\infty.$$